# Reduce tick marks in xyplot in R with DateTime in Xaxis

Tags: r, datetime, plot

I am working with XYPLOTS, where x-axis is a DateTime variable and y-axis contains a numeric variable. Due to huge number of DateTime (for 3 days and every 15 mins there is a data point).
The graph looks good but the xaxis labels are merged together.

If i reduce the tick numbers, the labels can be seen clearly. I dont know how to change the tick numbers or limit the intervals for a DATETIME variable.

DateTime looks like this : `2014-04-08 17:00:00, 2014-04-08 17:15:00, ...` etc.

Code I use right now:

```
xyplot(upper + lower + New1 ~ DateTime,data = a1,type = "l",lty = c(2, 2, 1),lwd = c(1, 1, 3),col.line = c(rep("black",2), "red"), scales=list(x=list(rot=45)))
```

This dataset can be a good example except that, x is datetime not just year:

```
df <- data.frame(x=paste0(rep(1960:1999, each=4), paste0("Q", 1:4)), y=1:160)
```

How can I handle this!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same with ggplot. I used library(ggplot2) and library(scales) to handle the issue. It came out very well.